# UICollectionView is not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is my code in cellForItemAtIndexPath, where I want load cell of two collectionView. Here first one is loaded loaded perfectlly but second one is loaded properly.

```
} else if (collectionView == _collBanner) {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"bannerCell";

    NSDictionary *dictBanner = [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BannerCollectionViewCell *cell = (BannerCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BannerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    [cell setupBannerCell:dictBanner];

    return cell;
}
return nil;
}
```

And my sizeForItemAtIndexPath method is...

```
} else if (collectionView == _collBanner) {

    return CGSizeMake(_collBanner.frame.size.width -5, _collBanner.frame.size.height -2);
} else
    return CGSizeMake(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line must be in viewDidLoad

```
    [_collBanner registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BannerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: how to do that because here shows some error message if I paste that.

Comment: declare this line    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"bannerCell";  below import.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the order of following two lines:

```
BannerCollectionViewCell *cell = (BannerCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BannerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

The first one asks for a cell of `BannerCollectionViewCell` type, but for the `collectionView` to be able to dequeue it, the `BannerCollectionViewCell` has to be registered in the `collectionView`. Only the second line registers the cell type to the `collectionView`.

First you have to register the `BannerCollectionViewCell` type to the collectionView:

```
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BannerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

And only then you can dequeue cells using:

```
BannerCollectionViewCell *cell = (BannerCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

However, it is enough to register the cell only once, therefore the best way is to register the cell in the `viewDidLoad` (move the following line from `cellForItemAt` to `viewDidLoad`):

```
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BannerCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```